# Ant zip exclude directories

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to create a zip file with Ant - I'd like to exclude the src directory, but it is not working:

```
<zip basedir="${workspace.dir}"
     destfile="${build.output.dir}/SomeModule.zip"
     includes="${SomeLibrary}"
     excludes="SomeLibrary/lib/somejar.jar, **/src/**"
     defaultexcludes="no" />
```

When I look at the zip file the somejar.jar file is not included, but the src directory (and all sub-directories and *.java files) are included.

The directory structure before the zip is:

```
SomeLibrary
    `--src
    `--bin
    `--lib
```

Comment: Looks like you have both comma & space as seperator in excludes pattern set. Try using one of them : From https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html `excludes` : comma- or space-separated list of patterns of files that must be excluded. No files (except default excludes) are excluded when omitted. Also just use src/** as basedir value is provided to `zip` task.

Comment: I've tried the `excludes` attribute as `"SomeLibrary/lib/somejar.jar,**/src/**"` and `"SomeLibrary/lib/somejar.jar **/src/**"` with the same result.  I used `**src/**` because the src directory is a sub-directory of `${SomeLibrary}`

Comment: the `includes` attribute has a comma instead of an ending double quote, is this a typo that occurred when you posted the question, or is it also part of your Ant script?

Comment: It is a typo in the post - it is correct in the script (I will fix the post).  Thank you.